# find average for column with unique name (tic) and value in notepad++

Tags: python-3.x, list

this is first to me to try python. I have a question how to average the value with unique name (tic) in file txt like the picture. the data have 13000 items and value with zero need to remove. its pure using python ( I know pandas can figure it) thank you for answering.

```
gvkey   datadate    fyear   tic at
001004  20090531    2008    AIR 1377.5110
001004  20100531    2009    AIR 1501.0420
001004  20110531    2010    AIR 1703.7270
001004  20120531    2011    AIR 2195.6530
001004  20130531    2012    AIR 2136.9000
001004  20140531    2013    AIR 2199.5000
001013  20081031    2008    ADCT    
001013  20090930    2009    ADCT    1343.6000
001013  20100930    2010    ADCT    1474.5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Read your data in a `pandas` dataframe. Then `pandas` by default skips the `nan`, so you can convert 0's to `nan` and use `groupby`:

```
>> import pandas as pd

# Read in the file
df = pd.read_csv(r'PATH\FILE_NAME.txt',delimiter='\t')

# Replace with nan & Groupby and mean 
(df.replace(0, np.nan)
   .groupby('tic', as_index=False)
   .agg({'at': 'mean'}))
```

---

```
    tic           at
0  ADCT  1409.050000
1   AIR  1852.388833
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but i would like to know without using library pandas, sorry for inconvenience.